# In my select, I can't set the default option on the value i want

Tags: angularjs, select

I am fairly new at Angular, but i don't know what's left for me to try to solve this.

I have a message that i can translate with a button. This is all working properly. Like you can see in the image there is a list of languages in a select. 
The user thats logged on, has a userlanguage setting. This is dutch, english or french. (for the general translation of the app there are only 3 languages. These languages are used for the app's standard text.)
In the select there are a lot more languages, for translation of the message. All this is working properly, including the translation.

The problem i'm having is that when the page loads, i want the selected option to be the user's defaultlanguage. But instead of selecting (in my example, English), it stays at the empty line at the top of the select with an empty description. When i test code behind this it says its id is 'EN' which means he actually receives the value on load but for some reason its not selecting the right line. But when i look at the html the others values are all like this 'STRING:EN', 'STRING:AM', ...

I believe this is because i use a string as id, and it thinks the id's are not the same so it creates a new one without description. I'm not sure about any of this. I've tried setting the default option manually too, but that didn't work either.

[Listbox with translate button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jVNI.png) this is the image

[image]

The html page:

```
<select id="languageListbox" name="LanguageSelect" style="width: 140px;"
        ng-show="UI.message.iCanReply(messagedetail) && (!UI.message.actionsAreVisible(messagedetail) || UI.message.performActionsVisibleBecauseOfSize)"
        tabindex="0" aria-multiselectable="false"
        aria-expanded="false" role="listbox"
        ng-options="language.id as language.description for language in languages" 
        ng-model="selectedLanguage"
        ng-init="selectedLanguage.id = userLanguage">
</select>
```

The controller: (only parts)

```
 $scope.languages = myLanguages.translateLanguages;
 ...
 function init() {
    ...
    $scope.userLanguage = $sessionStorage.user.DefaultLanguage;
    ...
    }
```

The resource file:

```
app.constant("myLanguages", {
"languages": [
    { id: 'NL', description: 'Dutch' },
    { id: 'EN', description: 'English' },
    { id: 'FR', description: 'French' }
],
"translateLanguages": [
    { id: 'AF', description: 'Afrikaans' },
    { id: 'SQ', description: 'Albanian' },
    ...
    { id: 'NL', description: 'Dutch' },
    { id: 'EN', description: 'English' },
    ...
]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ng-options try adding `track by language.id`

I think with your ng-model being an object (rather than the language ID) you need to use the track by syntax to help AngularJS uniquely identify each item in the collection

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates

Comment: That worked thank you. There was a problem with code behind after but i resolved it. When users default language is French, the listbox is on French, but we can still change the language for translation like we wanted. Only problem is now when i change the language the description is empty but only the first time, i can change it again and then it shows.